# ZF2 multi-join column issue

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Using ZF2, I am trying to create multi-join SQL statement, however, I can't get the columns for the second table.

Here's what I have so far,

```
...extends TableGateway

$select = $this->getSql()->select();
$select->columns(array('*'));
$select->join('acl_privilege', "{$this->table}.rule_privilege_id = acl_privilege.privilege_id");
$predicate = new Where();
$select->where(
    array(
        $predicate->equalTo('rule_resource_id', $resourceId),
        $predicate->equalTo('rule_allow', 1)
    ),
    \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\PredicateSet::OP_AND
);

$rows = $this->selectWith($select);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns for the join table are in an array in the third parameter of the method join.

Comment: Thank you for the answer